# Unable to change state of checkbox dynamically using setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

Below is a simple react component with initial state of checkbox as false.

I am trying to change it dynamically using setState(). It does not work.

Here is my code:

```
        var Hello = React.createClass({
            getInitialState: function(){
                return {
                    checked : this.props.checked.toString() === "false" ? false : true
                };
            },
            render: function() {
            console.log("rendering==");
                return <div><input type = "checkbox" defaultChecked = {this.state.checked}/></div>;
            }
        });

        var compRef = React.render(<Hello checked = "false" />, document.body);

   Trying to change state after rendering the component

        setTimeout(function(){
        compRef.setState({checked: true})
        },3000);
```

I am unable to change the checkbox state using setState.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k913fL0f)

Answer (score 3):

By providing `defaultChecked` instead of `checked` you are creating [uncontrolled component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#uncontrolled-components).
*Uncontrolled* means that you can't control it by changing `defaultChecked`.
To change checkbox's state from code, you need to provide `checked` for it.

Here is updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p4ps7nob/

The other thing to consider is: [Props in getInitialState Is an Anti-Pattern](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to toggle the state of a checkbox input, you need to utilize `checked` with an `onChange` handler instead of using `defaultChecked`.